Gizmo for each point
I'm trying to add a gizmo for each of my vertices so I can edit a custom attribute for each vertex, as if I was using the "Set attribute" operator, but the for each zone seems to output just one gizmo, is this even possible?
If you wonder why I won't just have an object with a single vertex for each of my elements, its because blender struggles to manage many objects but can handle lots of vertices.



After a bit of testing, I think it isn't possible (yet). It appears each gizmo have to be declared in its own node. I couldn't find anything in the doc about gizmos&loops.
